# JHipster Registry could not show client applications metrics

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry

I created new JHipster microservice application for demo purpose. I used JHipster Registry version 4.1.1 and create a new UAA application.
Both applications started without error.

I want to show UAA application metrics in Registry Dashboard (Administration -> Metrics) but it cannot display and logout JHipster Registry automatically.
There is a log line in UAA application:

```
Enter: com.mycompany.repository.CustomAuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=2019-03-19T19:35:08.979Z, principal=access-token, type=AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException, message=Cannot convert access token to JSON}]]
```

Please let me know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Is the JHipster Registry running with the `uaa` profile?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it works after I include uaa profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the UAA architecture for microservices, the JHipster Registry needs to run with the `uaa` profile to properly manage the registered services.  Otherwise, it expects the services to use JWT by default.

The gateway's docker-compose file for the registry (`src/main/docker/jhipster-registry.yml`) comes preconfigured with the `uaa` profile.  If you launch the JHipster Registry some other way (such as a git clone or WAR file), make sure it includes the `uaa` profile.